# What is the diffrence beetween Days and TotalDays?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datetime

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between these two functions in C#? TotalDays and Days because I'm not sure which once I should use in my code? Sorry for the low information on this text, but there is not much I can talk about.

Comment: Read the documentation. [`TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `double` because it represents whole and fractional days whereas [`Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx) is an `int` and represents only whole days.

Comment: Sometime SO is easier/faster/etc than original documentation. Especially slow Microsoft msdn servers

Answer (score 49):

Since I haven't found a duplicate, I post my comment here:

Always read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx) first. [`TotalDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `double` because it represents whole and fractional days whereas [`Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx) is an `int` which represents only whole days.

That is even mentioned explicitly in the remarks sections of `TimeSpan.Days`/`TotalDays`:

> The Days property represents whole days, whereas the TotalDays
> property represents whole and fractional days.

One thing to note, as opposed to the other properties in `TimeSpan` like `Hours`/`TotalHours` there is no limit on `Days`. So it doesn't end with 30 or 365 (like `Hour` which ranges from -23 through 23) since there is no larger unit than year. So `Days` will always be the same number as `(int) ts.TotalDays`.

> A `TimeSpan` doesn't have a sensible concept of "years" because it
> depends on the start and end point. (Months is similar - how many
> months are there in 29 days? Well, it depends...) [J. Skeet]

Comment: Some useful examples here: https://zzz.buzz/2017/12/07/csharp-traps-and-pitfalls-timespan-days-and-totaldays/

Comment: The inclusion of `Days` is surprising because the number of seconds-per-day is actually variable (e.g. Leap Seconds). Looking at the source-code for the two properties I see the .NET code performs naive division on Ticks assuming a fixed number of ticks per day, which I think is incorrect.