# Problem with Countdown to expire function

Tags: c#

I want to add to my project countdown to expire column. I've created medicine database.

And I'm struggling on the countdown to expire a medicine But it's not showing the correct number of days to expire. The last column. I presented it on image:

[image]

My Expire Date function:

```
public void UpdateCountdown()
{
    DateTime d1;
    DateTime d2;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); // date now
        d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value); // expiry date column
        TimeSpan ts = d2- d1;

        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value = ts.Days;
        string Query3 = "Update Medicine set DaysLeft ='" + ts.Days + "'" + " where rowid ='" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "'";
        ExcecuteQuery(Query3);
        LoadData();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"something is wrong"* What is wrong? I've looked at the picture but I can't figure out about what's the problem

Comment: The problem is last column countdown to expire in days

Comment: It doesn;t show correct number of days to expire

Comment: I've corrected my question

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code line by line and see what happens. Are you getting the dates that you expect to see? Is the database getting updated as you think it should? Try narrowing down the problem to a specific line of code where an input is not producing the output or result you're expecting.

Comment: Use the debugger and look at the values of d1, d2, and ts.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: I just wanted that it will show how many days left to expire in the last column

Comment: I spoted something on your code, and as i recall you might be using 1 thing wrong there: the "ts.Days" is not the same as "ts.TotalDays". A TimeSpan object would return a format in number of days if you call the TotalDays property instead of the Days property.

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] to help you.  We have no idea whether the problem is that the number of days to expire is **totally wrong**, or **off by one**, or something else entirely.  The problem might be with your `Querry3` string -- but there might also be problems with `ExcecuteQuery()` and `LoadData()`.  You're more likely to get useful help here if you follow the suggestions from [ask], specifically the section ***Help others reproduce the problem***.

Comment: That being said, if the problem is that the number of days to expire is **off by one** then @SammuelMiranda's comment is relevant.  As explained in [What is the diffrence beetween Days and TotalDays?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25212667/3744182), `ts.Days` is just `(int) ts.TotalDays` -- i.e. the number of days rounded down.  Maybe you want it rounded up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533285/calculate-period-expires-date-in-second-or-minutes-or-hours-or-days) SO answer which is done as per below.

[image]

```
public class DateHelper
{
    public static string CalculateExpirationTime(DateTime expiryDate)
    {
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        var dateDifference = (expiryDate - currentDate);

        if (dateDifference.Days >= 1)
            return $"{ dateDifference.Days } day(s) remained";
        else if (dateDifference.Hours >= 1)
            return $"{ dateDifference.Hours } hour(s) remained";
        else if (dateDifference.Minutes >= 1)
            return $"{ dateDifference.Minutes } minute(s) remained";
        else if (dateDifference.TotalSeconds >= 1)
            return $"{ dateDifference.Seconds } second(s) remained";

        return "Expired!";
    }
}
```

Form code where in this case the button code outputs to Visual Studio's output window.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("NameColumn", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("DateColumn", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Columns.Add("ExpireColumn", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add("Jane", new DateTime(2021,12,1));
        table.Rows.Add("Mike", new DateTime(2021,12,10));
        table.Rows.Add("Karen", new DateTime(2021,12,23));
        table.Rows.Add("Anne", new DateTime(2022,1,1));

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            table.Rows[rowIndex].SetField("ExpireColumn", 
                DateHelper.CalculateExpirationTime(
                    table.Rows[rowIndex].Field<DateTime>("DateColumn")));
        }

        _bindingSource.DataSource = table;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;

    }
    private void IterateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = (DataTable)_bindingSource.DataSource;

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < table.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(table.Rows[rowIndex]["ExpireColumn"]);
        }
    }
}
```